# Is there a way to find an aircraft's statistics?

Tags: air-travel, aircraft

Given a flight's tail-number, is there a way to search for the on-time statistics of that plane?

So far I've only found ways to search for on-time statistics per route.

Comment: Just curious, why the superstition?

Comment: No superstition... Airline is denying me compensation for a cancelled flight. Their claim is that the cancellation was due to "force majeure", as they could not anticipate a technical problem in a plane that was "in perfect technical condition"

Comment: So what you're actually looking for is maintenance statistics.

Comment: I could hope for the maintenance records, but I don't expect to find them in a publicly available database...

Comment: On-time statistics have very little to do with the technical condition of the aircraft. A few delays are because an aircraft must be pulled from service for unscheduled maintenance, but that's a small fraction of total delays. You will not be able to argue poor technical condition based on flights being late.

Comment: Find yourself a nice brick wall and repeatedly bang your head against it.  It'll be more fun and far more productive than attempting to prove that an aircraft had a pre-existing problem causing your delay.

Answer (score 3):

Flightradar24 provides data by airport, by route and by plane:

http://flightradar24.com/data

Example:

http://flightradar24.com/data/airplanes/tc-jjj

Answer (score 1):

To be quite honest I think you are barking up the wrong tree but you can try and use a suggestion from [Airliners.net thread](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/tech_ops/read.main/260236/) on maintenance records.

It may be possible to receive at least some information on aircraft maintenance from [Plane Fax](https://www.planefax.com/pfrorderreportjotform.html) but as was suggested these may have be a matter of public record.  But if you feel like spending $99 for a report let us know if this was useful.

Though you would have a very difficult time proving that a plane that arrived to an airport with no issues reported have had problems severe enough with that particular piece and that airline knew about it but didn't fix.

But good luck.

Answer (score -3):

http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightRating/flightRatingByRoute.do 
I think thats what you're looking for

Comment: do let me know if that is correct.

Comment: -1 I think the OP wants statistics by aircraft, not flight number nor route.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not useful in my case. I want to know the specific plane's statistics, as there were several planes rotating on that route. Also, this resource only shows statistics for active routes; my route wasn't active in the past couple of weeks so it doesn't show there.